# не добавляется картинка для статьи в django

Tags: django, sqlite, django-admin

Добавляю картинку в админку.
[image: Добавляю картинку в админку.]
Нажимаю "Сохранить и продолжить редактирование" картинка - пропадает. 
[image: Нажимаю "Сохранить и продолжить редактирование" картинка - пропадает]

Как исправить?

settings.py

`STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)`
`MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`

URLS

`from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns = [....
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

БД - sqlite3
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Папку для картинки создал?

Comment: img = models.ImageField('скриншот', upload_to='blog/images', default='', blank=True)

Comment: я имею ввиду папку images, по тому пути которые ты настроил, создал на компьютере?

Comment: да, добавил. blog/images

Comment: Ну смотри, если папка существует, то всё должно работать. У тебя прописано default="" в настроках поля, тоесть пустая строка по умолчанию, скорее всего она и сохраняется. Могу предложить только убрать дефолт, и по исключениям отдебажить ручками.

Comment: Подорожник помог, спасибо)